# Android 14: how to show read media permission request with "Allow all" again?

Tags: android, permissions

Android 14 has introduced "[Grant partial access to photos and videos](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/14/changes/partial-photo-video-access)" which user can choose to select specific photo/video for the app to access.

As the document says, when app request permissions like READ_MEDIA_IMAGES or READ_MEDIA_VIDEO, user can see a dialog contains the following options:

- **Select photos and videos**: New in Android 14. The user selects the specific photos and videos that they want to make available to your app.
- **Allow all**: The user grants full-library access to all photos and videos on the device.
- **Don't allow**: The user denies all access.

If the user chooses Select photos and videos and your app later requests READ_MEDIA_IMAGES or READ_MEDIA_VIDEO again, the system displays a different dialog, giving the user a chance to grant full access, keep the current selection, or grant additional photos and videos. **After a certain period of time, the system directly shows the system picker instead**.

Now, I have seen exactly this behavior, but this is also a problem for my app users: what if user wants to grant all the media access to my app but the system always shows the photo picker directly instead?

I tried in my app to request access to more/new photo and video via READ_MEDIA_IMAGES and READ_MEDIA_VIDEO permissions. The dialog with 3 options will pop up in the first 2-3 times. If user choose to select photo and video during those opportunities, later the photo picker will be directly displayed without asking if user wants to "allow all" after that. The only solution is to go to app permission settings and manually grant that.

This is not very user friendly. Does anyone know how to display the 3-option dialog always?

Comment: Hi, any update for this? I also experienced the same issue. I tried calling the requestPermissions with READ_MEDIA_IMAGES and again but the app strangely did not show the dialog again

Answer (score 1):

Simple answer is you **CANNOT**.

I reported this issue on [Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/309842674) and got the following response.

> It is not possible to force the 3 button dialog to show.

> Similar to how android stops showing the dialog after the user selects "deny" multiple times, we stop showing the dialog after the user selects "select photos and videos" multiple times. Users can upgrade to "allow all" in app settings.