# Android 14 storage permission return denied once i select "Select photos and videos " option

Tags: react-native, android-permissions, android-14, react-native-permissions, react-native-image-crop-picker

Android 14 storage permission return denied once i select "Select photos and videos "  option. It works fine when "Allow All" is selected . I am using `react-native-permissions` in combination with `react-native-image-crop-picker` to select images from gallery.

[[image]]

Comment: similar issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76917889/android-14-how-to-show-read-media-permission-request-with-allow-all-again you can check this post answer